# Create unique list from 2 columns and sum values per row based on that unique list from 2 value columns

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Having scoured numerous posts I am still struggling to find a solution for a report I am trying to transition over to PowerBI, from MS Excel.

**Problem**

Create a table in the report section of PowerBI, which has a unique list of currencies (based on 2 columns) and their corresponding FXexposure, which are defined based on each currency leg from 2 columns. Below I have shown the source data and workings I use in Excel, which i am trying to replicate.

Source data (from database table)

| a | b | d | d | e | f | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Instrument** | **Currency 1** | **Currency 2** | **FX nominal 1** | **FX nominal 2** | **FXNom1 - Gross** | **FXNom2 - Gross** |
| FWD EUR/USD | EUR | USD | -7.965264529 | 7.90296523 | 7.97 | 7.90 |
| FWD USD/JPY | USD | JPY | 1.030513307 | -1.070305687 | 1.03 | 1.07 |
| Instrument 1 | USD |  | 1.75862819 |  | 1.76 | 0.00 |
| Instrument 2 | USD | TRY | 0 | 3.45E-04 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| Instrument 3 | JPY |  | 1.121782037 |  | 1.12 | 0.00 |
| Instrument 4 | EUR |  | 6.2505079 |  | 6.25 | 0.00 |
| FWD EUR/CNH | EUR | CNH | 0.007591392 | 3.00E-09 | 0.01 | 0.00 |
| Instrument 5 | RUB |  | 6.209882675 |  | 6.21 | 0.00 |

F2 = ABS(FX nominal 1)
G2 = ABS(FX nominal 2)

**Report output in excel**

| a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **FX** | **Long** | **Short** | **Net** | **Gross ** |
| 0 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| RUB | 6.21 | 0.00 | 6.21 | 6.21 |
| EUR | 6.26 | -7.97 | -1.71 | 14.22 |
| JPY | 1.12 | -1.07 | 0.05 | 2.19 |
| USD | 10.69 | 0.00 | 10.69 | 10.69 |
| CNH | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| TRY | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

My Excel formulas are below to recreate what i am looking for.

```
A2:  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2, 1/(COUNTIF(Report!$A$1:A1,Data!$B$2:$B$553)=0), Data!$B$2:$B$553), LOOKUP(2, 1/(COUNTIF(Report!$A$1:A1, Data!$C$2:$C$553)=0), Data!$C$2:$C$553))

B2: =((SUMIFS(Data!$D$2:$D$553, Data!$B$2:$B$553, Report!$A2, Data!$D$2:$D$553, ">0"))+(SUMIFS(Data!$E$2:$E$553, Data!$C$2:$C$553, Report!$A2, Data!$E$2:$E$553, ">0")))

C2: =((SUMIFS(Data!$D$2:$D$553, Data!$B$2:$B$553, Report!$A3, Data!$D$2:$D$553, "<0"))+(SUMIFS(Data!$E$2:$E$553, Data!$C$2:$C$553, Report!$A3, Data!$E$2:$E$553, "<0")))

D2: =(SUMIF(Data!$B$1:$B$553,Report!$A3,Data!$D$1:$D$553)+SUMIF(Data!$C$1:$C$553,Report!$A3,Data!$E$1:$E$553))

E2: =(SUMIF(Data!$B$1:$B$554,Report!$A3,Data!$F$1:$F$554)+SUMIF(Data!$C$1:$C$554,Report!$A3,Data!$G$1:$G$554))
```

Now I believe I've managed to find a hack by using the UNIQUE/SELECTCOLUMNS function, but when you try and graph the output it is very small (as if there is other data it is trying to find behind the scenes). Note i tend to filter on date to get the output I need (this is mapped using relationships across other data tables).

```
FX =
DISTINCT (
UNION (
SELECTCOLUMNS ( DATA, "Date", [DATE], "Currency", [CURRENCY1],  "FXNom", [FXNOMINAL1] ),
SELECTCOLUMNS ( DATA, "Date", [DATE], "Currency", [CURRENCY2], ,"FXNom", [FXNOMINAL2] )
)
)
```

If anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful as I still feel my workaround is more of a lucky hack.

Thanks!

Comment: so, is the issue that it is looking for "other data behind the scenes" or something else?

Comment: Hey Sam. I don't its more "data behind the scenes", more probably my attempt to get it to work isn't perfect. hence seeing if anyone else would attempt this another way.

Comment: So, Negatives in D or E are short, Positives in D or E are long,  Net = short + long, Gross = Abs(short) + Abs(long)?

Comment: Your approach looks correct to me.   I don't think you would want the DISTINCT.  Although duplicated values are unlikely with so much precision, you wouldn't want two identical positions squashed into one.   I wonder if your charting looks small because you are expecting cumulative values across date?  You would need to create yet another measure for an aggregating value like that.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you're using looks nearly ideal.   From a dimensional model perspective, you want one column for values and one column for currency labels.   So selecting those pairs as different tables and appending with UNION is the right way to go.  Generally, I think it's better to do all the transformation you can in power query, using DAX this way can lead to some limitations.

But if we're going with DAX, I do think you want to get rid of DISTINCT.  This could cause identical positions to be collapsed into a single row and you'd lose data this way.

```
FX = 
UNION (
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( FX_Raw, "Date", "FakeDate", "Currency", [CURRENCY 1], "FXNom", [FX nominal 1] ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( FX_Raw, "Date", "FakeDate", "Currency", [CURRENCY 2], "FXNom", [FX nominal 2] )
)
```

And then a few measures:

```
Long = 
   CALCULATE(sum(FX[FXNom]), FX[FXNom] >= 0)
Short = 
   CALCULATE(sum(FX[FXNom]), FX[FXNom] < 0)
Gross = 
   SUMX( FX, if(FX[FXNom] > 0, FX[FXNom], 0-FX[FXNom]))
Net = 
   SUM(FX[FXNom])
```

Seems to produce the desired result:

[image]

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Thank you very much. It was my first time reading through multiple forums and figuring out the best way to approach this - looks like I was nearly there...no cherry on top though. What is the proposal for PowerQuery if I may ask? happy to be sent links and I can read up on it.